jax library error jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DNN library initialization failed
I am working on a code that uses the Jax library, and I run into this error over and over again no matter how I tried to configure my environment:
2024-08-20 16:26:58.037892: E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:439] 

Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2024-08-20 16:26:58.037952: E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:443] Memory usage: 46637514752 bytes free, 47587131392 bytes total.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GPU_pairwise_pipline.py", line 260, in <module>
    SSMD_res_with_indices = process_blocks(train_set_sick, train_set_healthy, block_size)
  File "GPU_pairwise_pipline.py", line 172, in process_blocks
    mean_block1_sick, var_block1_sick = cal_mean_and_var(block1_sick)
  File "GPU_pairwise_pipline.py", line 17, in cal_mean_and_var
    data_jax = jnp.array(data)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py", line 2035, in array
    out = _array_copy(object) if copy else object
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py", line 4447, in _array_copy
    return copy_p.bind(arr)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 380, in bind
    return self.bind_with_trace(find_top_trace(args), args, params)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 383, in bind_with_trace
    out = trace.process_primitive(self, map(trace.full_raise, args), params)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 815, in process_primitive
    return primitive.impl(*tracers, **params)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/lax.py", line 4486, in _copy_impl
    return dispatch.apply_primitive(prim, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 132, in apply_primitive
    compiled_fun = xla_primitive_callable(
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/util.py", line 284, in wrapper
    return cached(config._trace_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/util.py", line 277, in cached
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 223, in xla_primitive_callable
    compiled = _xla_callable_uncached(
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 253, in _xla_callable_uncached
    return computation.compile().unsafe_call
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 2323, in compile
    executable = UnloadedMeshExecutable.from_hlo(
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 2645, in from_hlo
    xla_executable, compile_options = _cached_compilation(
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 2555, in _cached_compilation
    xla_executable = dispatch.compile_or_get_cached(
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 497, in compile_or_get_cached
    return backend_compile(backend, computation, compile_options,
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 314, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 465, in backend_compile
    return backend.compile(built_c, compile_options=options)
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: FAILED_PRECONDITION: DNN library initialization failed. Look at the errors above for more details.
(jax-env) mikabell@hanamel:~$  sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

This is what I'm working with:
nvidia-smi
Tue Aug 20 16:52:27 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.08              Driver Version: 545.23.08    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA L40                     On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0              79W / 300W |    894MiB / 46068MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA L40                     On  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P8              34W / 300W |     21MiB / 46068MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA L40                     On  | 00000000:61:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P8              34W / 300W |     21MiB / 46068MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA L40                     On  | 00000000:62:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P8              35W / 300W |     21MiB / 46068MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3774      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    999897      C   ...physics/rtk243/anaconda3/bin/python      868MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      3774      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A      3774      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A      3774      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

There is no memory problem, and I have set up my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to where my CUDNN version I downloaded is:
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/a/home/cc/chemist/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/


#define CUDNN_MAJOR 8
#define CUDNN_MINOR 9

I'm working with these Jax installations :
pip show jax jaxlib
Name: jax
Version: 0.4.13
Summary: Differentiate, compile, and transform Numpy code.
Home-page: https://github.com/google/jax
Author: JAX team
Author-email: jax-dev@google.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /home/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: importlib-metadata, ml-dtypes, numpy, opt-einsum, scipy
Required-by:
---
Name: jaxlib
Version: 0.4.13+cuda12.cudnn89
Summary: XLA library for JAX
Home-page: https://github.com/google/jax
Author: JAX team
Author-email: jax-dev@google.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /home/mikabell/anaconda3/envs/jax-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: ml-dtypes, numpy, scipy
Required-by:

Please I would appreciate someone's help in understanding why I get the same error over and over again..
Thank you!

There are many existing issues discussing this exact error: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agoogle%2Fjax+%22FAILED_PRECONDITION%3A+DNN+library+initialization+failed%22&type=issues Have you tried any of the solutions mentioned in those?

This error can typically mean that your CUDA and CUDNN versions are incompatible with the jaxlib build you are trying to install.
You're using a version of JAX that is quite old (v0.4.13, when the most recent release is v0.4.31) and you're using a newer CUDA version (v12.3), which was released six months after the release of JAX v0.4.13. Given this, I suspect the issue can be fixed by installing a more recent version of jax and jaxlib that is compatible with your CUDA version.
It appears from your traceback that you're using Python 3.8; recent JAX versions do not support Python 3.8, so fixing this will probably also involve installing a more recent Python version – it would be good to do this soon anyway, because Python 3.8 is reaching its end of life in a few weeks (October 2024).
Once you've updated to Python 3.9 or newer, you can update JAX this way:
$ pip install -U "jax[cuda12]"

and it should fix your issue.
